# Flash player needed in Firefox?

Tags: firefox, flash

I'm using Ubuntu 14.04 LTS, and I always installed every update needed.
But, I have a question now: I'm using Firefox now, and I can watch without any problem any video from youtube, for example. But, I didn't install the Adobe Flash Player (that firefox keeps asking me to install that)

I already searched for other answers, but since they were answered years ago, then I thing I'm going to ask for more updated information.

So, do I have to install it? Never had any problems with that.

Thank you guys for helping me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adobe Flash player is proprietary. Check boxes for proprietary software in Software and Updates setting, and then go to Software Center , and look for it there. Also install QuickJava addon in Firefox (type in address bar `about:addons`). This will help you to easily enable Java and Flash in Firefox. This is my usual set up in Ubuntu. Also, if you don't need flash for anything but YouTube,  just use HTML 5 plugins from Firefox - that's what I do on Fedora.

Another alternative is Google Chrome or Chromium browsers. They come with pepper-flash player, which is a variation of Adobe's.  And it's going to be supported too.

Comment: Also keep in mind that Flash 11.2 is last version for Linux, although they provide security updates. Eventually you may just wanna go with HTML 5 completely

Comment: Hmmmm, I could try to install that. But, if what @Xieerqi is true, then I could just stick with the flash. But what flash? The Adobe or the one that comes installed?

Comment: @Nori-chan Adobe Flash is one your Firefox keeps asking.  So like I said , Adobe's last release for Linux is 11.2.

Comment: Well, since I'm using flash to just watch Youtube videos *and maybe later watch Crunchyroll), then I could just stick with the default flash, right (assuming it is being updated, if not, them I will get Adobe flash).

Comment: Yup, just consider your needs. Plus like I said HTML 5 is already here - it may eventually be a decent replacement for Adobe's flash altogether

Comment: Hmmmm, just let me know if the default flash is secure to use. Since my most important thing is security, then I'm ready to use something that's been receiving security updates.

Comment: Well that's whole another topic. Can't say anything about that for sure.  I've read that Adobe Flash has security issues. It's actually weird that you can watch YouTube although Adobe Flash isn't installed. I checked my Firefox plugins just now and it has DivX Web Player.  That's probably what comes by default. Again,  can't tell much about security there. Assuming most hackers would target Adobe Flash cuz its on most systems, you're safe with default.  Or like I said before , use html 5. So far we haven't heard of security holes in that department

Comment: Here's something about computer security, and she talks about Flash,too , around 3:40: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kQkjzwWgIvY&list=UUBE-FO9JUOghSysV9gjTeHw  | She basically suggests disabling flash, so having HTML 5 instead of flash is probably best security solution.

Comment: Nobody mentioned here, there is a project in `Github` to make it possible to use `pepper` plugin in Firefox http://www.webupd8.org/2014/05/fresh-player-plugin-pepper-flash.html

Comment: Ok then, looks like I will use HTML5, but how can I use it and disable flash?I'm looking for it.... (didn't watched the video, right now the internet is too slow).

Comment: If Adobe Flash not installed , then its not enabled. Remember I mentioned QuickJava addon ? You can disable it through there. Also , just play around with Firefox settings.  about:addons page lists all plugins Firefox has, and you can enable/disable them there.

Comment: Just tried quick java (quickjavaplugin.blogspot.com) and it works really well. Strangely, I can still play videos without flash. Just a little off-topic, but what a proxy does? I can see here to activate or not.

Comment: Em . . . <.< That I can't tell you. As far as networking goes, I'm still a  noob in that department.

Comment: Strange, I disabled every plugin, yet I can still watch youtube videos (I even disabled the DivX web player and other media players. Maybe it's the Ubuntu Firefox Modifications?

Comment: I just remembered this: Right click on a video when you watch it. It should have " About   . . . " option there and ir should tell you what player is used.

Comment: Strange, I disabled every plugin, and when Right-clicking on a video, it says "About HTML5 player". But,in a few videos, Youtube says "In this moment, Your browser doesn't recognize the available video formats"

Comment: Hmm, I wanna try to uninstall the Adobe Flash on my own machine, and disable all plugins like you did, and see what's gonna happen. Can you post me some of the videos that said "not recognized" ?

Comment: And if I'm not mistaken , videos on youtube are all available in different formats - some in flv some in other. But I may be wrong

Comment: @Xieerqi, I'm brazilian, so sorry that this video is in portuguese language: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kUmla3BouUY&list=PLQamLLzUTEJys6afnAR656xq0_cCKndpL. Now I will see how to fix this problem...

Comment: So, I've disabled every plug in and flash as well, and yes - still can watch youtube, and even the video you posted. Turns out Firefox supports html 5 without external add-ons ! https://www.youtube.com/html5  When I go to this page it shows what formats firefox supports ( HTMLVideoElement, H.264, and WebM VP8 ). It also says "default player is used", but I've no idea what that default player is, because I've got everything disabled

Comment: @Xieerqi Good to nkow that you have no problems. I still can watch the video, but that's not a problem for me, so I will continue to use my laptop normally.

Comment: Sorry for the double post. But looks like that I have to install flash player (now the problem is that I can't watch Crunchyroll videos), but I will look for another solution.